# Как создать новую страницу в php

Tags: php, html

Я создал этот скрипт, суть которого в создании страницы
`.html` . Есть два `input`-а. Первый определяет имя страницы а второй ее содержимое. Код не работает, возможно, Я допустил ошибку, ведь я ноль в php.

Мой код:

```
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
 Name <input type="text" name="nameof" id="name" value="yourname.html"> (dont forget .html at end)
</form>
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
 Text <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="<b>your text</b> hello <i> example </i>">
 <input type="submit" name="select" value="select" onclick="select()" />
 </form>
 
 <?php
 function select(){
  $name= $_GET['name'];
  $data= $_GET['text']; 
  $fp = fopen($file, "w"); 
  fwrite($fp, $data); 
  fclose($fp); 

 } ?>
```

Прошу помочь. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `onclick=select()` это вызов функции select  в js. а `<?php function select()`  это функция в пхп. они никак не связаны между собой.

Comment: а есть какой-либо другой способ вызвать php функцию?

Comment: @fedinovmaksim Вам надо отправить запрос на сервер (через AJAX, например), а на сервере уже вызывать функцию. Сейчас Вы пытаетесь на клиенте выполнить PHP, что для этого языка в принципе невозможно по определению.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar нужно создать отдельный файл с функцией и вызвать ее через сервер?

Comment: @fedinovmaksim Да

Comment: @VladimirGonchar , не подскажете функцию через которую можно такое сделать? Я не смог найти :(

Comment: @fedinovmaksim не смогли найти, или даже не пытались ? Вам даже направление дали - Ajax. Осталось лишь загуглить Ajax + php.

Comment: Ааа точно, спасибо, я совсем забыл про Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо два `form`. Попробуйте что-то такое:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
        Name <input type="text" name="nameof" id="name" value="yourname"> 
        Text <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="<b>your text</b> hello <i> example </i>">
        <input type="submit" name="select" value="select">
    
    </form>
    
    <? php
     function select(){
      $name= $_POST['nameof'];
      $data= $_POST['text'];
      $fp = fopen($name.'.html', "w+");
      fwrite($fp, $data);
      fclose($fp);
     }
     if (exist(POST['select'])){
    select();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).